# Python 3.7.9: No module named 'discord'

Tags: python, package, discord, discord.py

**EDIT**
I was using the wrong interpreter in VS Code :|

I just switched from a web-based IDE(repl.it) to VS Code on my Mac running Catalina. I have installed 3.7.9 and set it as global, and of course installed discord.py with pip. However, running `import discord` still causes the following error to appear: `import discord ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'`

[image]

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`, and also inside vscode show us the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: pip --version
```pip 20.1.1 from /Users/NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)```


sys.path
```>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Users/NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7', '/Users/NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages']```

Comment: What is your exact import statement?  Is it `import discord.py` or `import discord`?

Comment: Also can you show us the directory listing of `/Users/NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

Comment: I was hoping to see a directory listing, not `pip list`.  (It's easier to read if you add these to the question instead of as comments.)

Comment: I just added it to the post, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Well, I'm grasping at straws here, but why is `SITE-PACKAGES` in all caps at the top of that screenshot?  That doesn't match the sys.path you posted.

Comment: that is just the font for VS code

Comment: Can you open a shell window and do an actual ls of that directory?

Comment: not sure if you get a notif for this, but yeah i got it

Comment: I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `pip3 install discord.py`, pip may be installing it for python 2 only.